# Space Problems?

Tags: filesystems, raspberry-pi, sd-card, raspbian

I just got a new SD card for my pi. Trying to install node.js, I ran out of space (I've also recently installed a LAMP server system). But, when I plug it into my main (Windows-Ubuntu dual-boot) computer, windows says it's only half full. What's going on here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So I solved the problem on my own, and am just posting here for the benefit of anyone who has the same problem in future. Once you know the solution, its pretty obvious that this question should have been on the Raspberry Pi StackExchange.

Anyway, my problem was that the partition hadn't been expanded to fill the SD card. Once I ran `sudo raspi-config` and fixed that, everything was fine.